# Opening Illustrator CC 2015 without file recovery

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

The Illustrator auto recovery feature is nice. However, is there any way to switch it off before or during the start of Illustrator CC 2015?

If the file is small but makes the program hang, it opens the file more or less immediately but hangs after that.

Comment: Found a answer. On a PC if you move or delete the recovery file, Illustrator CC starts normally. The recovery file is located in User/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator 19 Settings/ [language folder name]/ [x64/x32?]/DataRecovery/

Comment: If the solution you found worked well to solve your issue, you can post the comment above as an answer, and then mark it as "accepted"!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to simply save and close your files before closing your computer. Unless you're crashing a lot.

You could uncheck the boxes for **the data recovery** in the file handling & clipboard section, recovery in your Illustrator Preferences.

[image: Automatic recovery Illustrator]

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/crash-file-data-recovery.html

If you don't want to turn the data recovery off, in general you can also cancel any action in process by pressing "command" +  "." on Mac.